# Python. Efficient way to remove emojis and some punctuation from a large dataset

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have 200k rows with messages in a pandas dataframe. Each message on average contains 230 characters sprinkled with emojis like these .

Now i want to filter out everything except lower and upper English and Russian letters and these symbols: `#@/:%.,_-`

What would be the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: "What would be the most efficient way of doing that?" → This is a few tens of MB of data. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `str.replace` with `^` inversion.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('[^\w\s#@/:%.,_-]', '', flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: How can I apply the same method but want to keep emojis?